# How to migrate SQL Server Image datatype to Azure blob container?

Tags: sql-server, azure, cloud, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

We are migrating our data from on-premise to the cloud. One requirement is to store the attachments (`.pdf`, `.txt`, `.png` etc) data from a SQL Server table in Azure blob containers in a particular format.

The table structure looks like this:

```
TABLE 
(
    Id int, 
    Name nvarchar, 
    EntityId int, 
    RecordId int, 
    BlobData image
)
```

The files should be saved in following way in the container.

Folder structure : `Container//Entity ID//Record ID//Files`

For example:

```
BlobContainer//10//1//xyz.pdf, png.png
```

Here I consider both files `xyz` and `abc` to belong to same entity (10) and record (1).

I tried Azure Data Factory, but I am unable to find a proper solution as I am facing a source sink mismatch issue when trying to use "Copy Data" activity in a pipeline.

Has anyone faced the same problem or do you have any other solution to complete this task?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and error you are facing.

Comment: @PratikLad I created a pipeline and used copy data activity where the source dataset is sql server table using self hosted integration runtime.
The Sink i am choosing is Azure Blob Storage / Binary file type. Now validating this give me the error that source should be binary too .
In a nut shell i am unable to parse each row and then select the blobData to convert it into binary and store it using other column details.

Comment: `image` is a deprecated type, use `varbinary(max)` instead. There is no built in tool to do this using blob storage. You would have to write a script to load the values into blob storage and save the ID into the database

Comment: When using binary as sink, we should also use a binary source. Do you only want your sink file to be binary file only?